# What is the Russian translation for "I (don't) feel like doing..."?

Tags: перевод, выражения

I was wondering, how would we translate "I feel like doing *something*." and the negative version in Russian?

This is a fixed expression in English, so I suppose a similar idiomatic expression would be possible in Russian, even if with a different structure.

After a quick search, I found:

> **Мне (не) охота это делать.**
>   *I (don't) feel like doing that.*

So by using this structure *"I feel like dancing."* would be:

> **Мне охота танцевать.**

Is it correct?

Answer (score 7):

"Мне (не) хочется" would be a closer match to "I (don't) feel like doing something." "Мне (не) охота" is a more colloquial and rarely used version.

Comment: Is it becoming obsolete? What would be a more formal version? Since I suppose "Мне (не) хочется" is not too formal... Could you include these points in your answer? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I believe, the OP is also not so formal so the translation provided here is the most precise. However, if you want to make it somewhat more formal, you can say «Мне бы (не) хотелось».

Comment: @Alenanno And no, «мне (не) хочется» or «мне (не) хотелось бы» is widely used. Note however that the latter I'd translate as _I would (not) like ...ing_.

Answer (score 3):

Предложенные в других ответах варианты звучат как-то пластмассово, не живо. Я бы переводил так: *"Думаю, мне стОит...", "Кажется, было бы неплохо...", "А почему бы мне не..."*

```
Неплохо бы прогуляться!

Думаю, мне стоит подкрепиться!

А не выпить ли нам чаю?
```

Что касается *охота/не охота"*, то *охота* звучит старовато, а *не охота* применяется чаще и звучит естественно.

Comment: It should probably be "А не выпить ли *мне* чаю?". Although "I feel like (doing smth.)" *may* imply an invitation, I think it primarily states what I myself, rather than *we*, feel like doing at the moment. Another option could be: "Я бы (прогулялся, пообедал, потанцевал)!"

Comment: Да, основной посыл тут - "Вы как хотите, а я уж точно попью чайкУ"

Answer (score 1):

'I feel like ...' close to 'настроение', 'настрой', 'дух' - mood, tune, spirits.
I feel like dancing - (У меня) настроение танцевать/потанцевать
I don't feel like dancing - (У меня) нет настроения танцевать/потанцевать
I feel like doing that - Я настроен это делать
I don't feel like doing that - Я не настроен это делать/Я не в настроении это делать/Я не в духе это делать

The different between "Мне (не) хочется" and "(У меня) настроение" is hard to explain, I'll try. If I say 'Мне (не) хочется', in most cases I can answer on next question

- 'Why?'
- 'Because of ...'.

It's probably a rational thing.

But when I use 'настроение' - don't need any explanation.

- 'Why?'
- 'Just because'

It's an irrational thing, pure emotional, I can't answer even to myself, why.

By the way, I agree with КуЪ: "охота" and "настроение" are rarely used in a positive sense (in the affirmative). It's somehow lifeless, expressionless. But "охота" and "настроение" are commonly used in negative sense (denial). So, I think I found a better translation:

"I feel like (do smth) [right now]" better translated as "Я бы по+(делал что-нибудь) [сейчас]"

Example: "Я бы по+(рисовал, спал, танцевал, пил, лежал, ехал, смотрел, слушал, ...) [сейчас]" means: "Я бы порисовал сейчас", "Я бы поспал", ...

Summary: "Я бы по+(imperfect verb first-person past tense) [сейчас]".
Prefix "по" is very important - "Я бы порисовал". "Я бы рисовал" - completely different meaning.

"I don't feel like (do smth) [right now]" better translated as "Мне не охота (что-нибудь делать) [сейчас]" or "Я не хочу (что-нибудь делать) [сейчас]"
Example: "Мне не охота/Я не хочу рисовать (спать, танцевать, пить, лежать, ехать, смотреть, слушать, ...)"
Summary: "Мне не охота (verb infinitive) [сейчас]" or "Я не хочу (verb infinitive) [сейчас]"

Comment: Thanks eugene... I see you approached it from a whole different perspective. What is the different between "Мне (не) хочется" and "(У меня) настроение"? (Please don't answer in the comments, add it to the answer.)